# Passage Comprehension

Tags: comprehension

The following question appeared in an Indian company's recruitment exam.

> Read the passage carefully and answer the question that follows.
>
> The Postmaster, a native of Calcutta. took up his duties in the remote village of Ulapur. He felt very lonely and homesick. At times he wrote verses. Ratan was his only companion. She was an orphan girl. She did odd jobs for him. He talked to Ratan about his mother, brother and sister. That gave him much comfort. Ratan got very much attached to him. 
>   One day the Postmaster fell ill. Ratan nursed him like his mother. Afterwards the Postmaster applied for a transfer. It was rejected. So he resigned his job. Ratan expected him to take her with him. The Postmaster simply laughed at her idea. The laughter haunted her throughout the night. 
>   The Postmaster promised to ask his successor to take care of her. It offended her more. Ratan burst out weeping and said there was no need for that. Before his departure he gave her some money. She refused to accept it. While crossing the river in a boat he felt an impulse to go back and bring the girl. It was too late. Meetings and partings are numberless in human life. He consoled himself with this philosophy. Ratan had no such philosophy to console her. She was wandering about the post office with tears in her eyes, fondly hoping that her Postmaster would return.
>
> Choose the most appropriate option. 
>   What is the theme (or main idea) of the passage?
>
> A) We should not care for the people who help us.
>
> B) Human relationships have no monetary value.
>
> C) We should appreciate those who help us in life.
>
> D) We meet so many people in our lives and we cannot remember all of them.

The answer provided by them is B but I think option C is more accurate than option B.

Postmaster tried to give money to Ratan. If he had thought human relationships have no monetary value, he wouldn't have done it. While crossing the river, he felt an impulse to go back. This clearly means that he appreciates those who helped him in his life.

He’ll always remember her because if he wanted to forget about her the return idea wouldn’t have crossed his mind; he'll miss her caring.

The company has provided a deadline till tomorrow to notify them if in case multiple/no options are matching for a question or if the question is ambiguous or if the answer provided by them is wrong. So, should I notify them about this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I entirely agree that C is a better answer. The matter of money occurs but once in this passage, whereas the general theme is about a person who was kind but her kindness was not requited. This occurs in nearly every sentence.

What is interesting is that the passage is about someone who DIDN'T appreciate someone's kindness, but the reader is made to sympathize with the girl, and so the lesson is provoked by an example of what not to do.

BTW, if this was given in this way as part of your test I'd be concerned. The English is pretty rough, though it does occur to me that you might have translated it from a local language.

Comment: The passage is indeed translated. The Short Story "The Postmaster" was originally written in the language "Bangla" in the year 1891 by a famous poet named "Rabindranath Tagore".

Comment: By the way, this passage appeared in English during the test not in Bangla.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the "theme" of the passage is alluded to in the passage itself. "...Meetings and partings are numberless in human life...". The passage is about human relations and how they are transient. Hence I would argue that option D, while not the best answer, is the closest to what the passage is trying to convey.